# How to Read file from Hadoop using Java without command line

Tags: hadoop

I wanted to read file from hadoop system, I could do that using the below code

```
String uri = theFilename;
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
InputStream in = null;
try {
  in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
  IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
} finally {
  IOUtils.closeStream(in);
}
```

To run this file I have to run hadoop jar myjar.jar com.mycompany.cloud.CatFile /filepathin_hadoop
That works. But How can I do that same from other program, I mean without using hadoop jar command.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your **core-site.xml** to that Configuration object so it knows the URI for your HDFS instance.  This method requires **HADOOP_HOME** to be set.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path coreSitePath = new Path(System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME"), "conf/core-site.xml");
conf.addResource(coreSitePath);
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
// rest of code the same
```

Now, without using `hadoop jar` you can open a connection to your HDFS instance.

**Edit**:  Have to use conf.addResource(Path).  If you use a String arg it, looks in the classpath for that filename.

Comment: Have added the same piece of code and set the HADOOP_HOME parameter as env variable from eclipse, but still  System.out.println(hdfs.getHomeDirectory()); prints local file system directory.

Comment: I edited my answer; forgot to use a Path to the core-site.xml instead of a String.

Answer (score 0):

There is another configuration method set(parameterName,value). 
If you use this method, you dont have to specify the location of core-site.xml. This would be useful for accessing HDFS from remote location like webserver.

Usage as follows :

```
    String uri = theFilename;
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://10.132.100.211:8020/"); 
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
// Rest of the code
```